# Cancelling submission while using jquery submit

Tags: jquery

I'm submitting a form silently i.e without page refresh using jquery.submit() method. When user selects a file and click upload button upload starts and cancel button is enabled. But i don't know how to cancel this upload in between. Official jquery documentation says

**"we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler"** ,but i didn't understand how to use this in my case. 
Below is the code i'm using to submit the form.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: If you don't want the form to submit, why are you calling `$("#form").submit()`

Comment: i'm cancelling uploading if user requests to do so.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? That would be helpful. And I believe you can only cancel a file upload if you are uploading asynchronously.  If you are using a regular file input with a form post, then you cannot cancel once the file is submit.

Comment: I'm using jquery.submit() method and i hope that it submits form asynchronously.

Comment: You cannot submit files asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's some confusion about how the jquery .submit() method is used.  From the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`,
>   `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.

What this means is that all this method does is actually handle the submit event of a form.  If you cancel the event, then your file upload is cancelled.  There is no inbetween.  You are either allowing the file to be uploaded, or you are cancelling the form submit (the upload) entirely.  Also, to use .preventDefault(), it would look like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});

$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // could also use return false; as a previous poster 
    // suggested but I have found e.preventDefault() to be more reliable
});
```

You may need to look into some 3rd party plugins to accomplish what you are trying to do.  One such plugin is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Once, the submit has reached the server there is nothing much you can do with it (the form).

Doing `return false;` can at most prevent a submit from occurring.

Comment: that's what i'm asking. When should i call this statement?

Comment: In your case, you can have another button outside the form that reloads the page, or something. My point is, you cannot cancel AFTER submit.

Comment: the form data is not uploaded completely. Its in between and user cancels the upload.

Comment: @SushilKumar: Have you tried using the `input type="reset" />` button? There is also an `input type="cancel"` but most people would advise against it.